# EPPlus Add Worksheet with Latest Version of Office Losses All Macros

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, excel-2016, vba

When you run the following code on a file that has any VBA macro's whatsoever:

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("Test.xlsm")))
{
    xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("TestTab");
    xlPackage.Save();
}
```

You get the following issue(upon opening the edited file):

> We found a problem with some content in 'Test.xlsm'. Do you want us to
>   recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook,
>   click Yes.
>   [image]

(if you click yes)

> Removed Part: /xl/vbaProject.bin part.  (Visual Basic for Applications
>   (VBA))
>   [image]

Then your VBA Marco is gone... I also have received:

> The Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) macros in the workbook are
>   corrupted and have been deleted. The macro corruption most likely
>   exists in the current file. To recover the macros, open a backup copy
>   of this file if you have one.
>   [image]

I only see this issue on the latest update(Office 365 Excel 1708 - 8431.2079). When I test on older versions of excel or on versions that have not been upgraded to the latest version I do not experience this issue.

It appears the latest office update has introduced this issue into the opening of files that have been modified(specifically when a new worksheet in inserted) by [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus)(Latest 4.5.0).

Has anybody else experienced this issue? Maybe someone has a work around of some sort. I was hoping not to have to dig into the source code :(

**Edit**: Took Mr. Pie's advise and cloned the ticket, maybe someone clever than me has some insight into source: [GitHub](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/5)

Comment: You might be better off adding this as an issue on the EPPlus github page ... https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues ... of course, that's relying on the author finding time to fix the problem, but this does sound like it might be an important problem that needs a quick fix. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jan Kallman was nice enough to [fix this](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/commit/945a4761fe01d133184cd2424e552a26591c30f8) in the latest release: 4.1.1

Simply upgrade your library to the newest version either through [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) or via [Github](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) directly. Issue should then be resolved.